# angular ngView shows 404 error when use with anchor tag

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

This is  my html code for ngView

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <a href="/tuto.jsp#/album/{{ album.name }}">{{ album.title }} </a>
    <div style="float: right">{{ album.date }}</div>
</div>
```

this is my angular config code.only the 2nd that come's with parametrs not working.other pages redirecting successfully[This image shows not working code part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrdTv.jpg).

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/albums", {
        controller : "ctrl",
        templateUrl : "album_list_partial.jsp"
    })
    .when("/albums/:album_name", {
        controller : "viewCtrl",
        templateUrl : 'album_view_partial.html'
    })
    .when("/", {
        redirectTo : "/albums"
    })
    .when("/404_page", {
        controller : "Controller404",
        templateUrl : "404_page_partial.jsp"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo : "/404_page"
    });

});
```

Comment: which angular version?  In angular 1.6+, you need `!#`.

Comment: yeah.i added..but still not working

Comment: i'm using 1.6.4 version..

Comment: so what does "not working" mean, exactly?  does it not load anything? does it load a different route? does it throw an error?  There isn't much to go on here.

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /tuto.jsp

it's shows 404 when i'm click the <a> tag.but i other 404_page i added was working correctly.

Comment: so it's not going to your redirect route?  That sounds like a server side issue.  What server are you using?

Comment: i'm using tomcat

Comment: is `/tuto.jsp` relative to your website root or your `app` directory or some other location?

Comment: it's website root

Comment: do you have a `<base href="/" />` in your HTML document?

Comment: No.i don't have. but the redirecting file also in the same location as /tuto.jsp